# Python ternary conditional for joining string

Tags: python, augmented-assignment

Answered by Martijn Pieters. Thank you.
It is because statement vs expression.
And because .join() does not mutate (is a pure function), so it needs to be assigned to a variable.

Question:
What is the reason for this oddity?

Goal:

```
if base == 'T':
    RNA_seq += 'U'
else:
    RNA_seq += base
```

This following method works:

```
# += in expression1 and .join() in expression2
RNA_seq += 'U' if base == 'T' else RNA_seq.join(base)
# Edit note: RNA_seq.join(base) works because it returns `base`
#       aka. RNA_seq += 'U' if base == 'T' else base
```

However the following does NOT work:

```
# Using += on both expressions
RNA_seq += 'U' if base == 'T' else RNA_seq += base
```

or

```
# Using .join() for both expressions
RNA_seq.join('U') if base == 'T' else RNA_seq.join(base)
```

The results are the same in both Python2 and Python3.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like all assignment, `+=` is a *statement*. You cannot ever put statements in an expression. The right-hand expression (everything after `+=`) is evaluated *first*, the result of which is then used for the augmented assignment.

You *can* do:

```
RNA_seq += 'U' if base == 'T' else base
```

Now the expression resolves either to `'U'`, or `base`, depending on the value of `base`.

If `'U' if base == 'T' else RNA_seq.join(base)` worked, then that means that `RNA_seq.join()` returns a new value and doesn't mutate `RNA_seq` in-place. `RNA_seq.join('U') if base == 'T' else RNA_seq.join(base)` would then also return a new value, leaving the original value bound by `RNA_seq` unchanged, and you didn't assign it back to `RNA_seq`.

Comment: I see! Thank you.
My understanding of ternary conditional / assignment was off.
It is var += (expression1 if condition else expression2) instead of my wrong understanding. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy one-liner that does the same transcription from DNA to RNA (T->U):

```
RNA = lambda x:''.join([{'A':'A','C':'C','G':'G','T':'U'}[B] for B in x])
print RNA("AGTCAGCAT") #example sequence results in AGUCAGCAU
```